# CSS3 :not() selector, working around contained elements

Tags: html, css

I am moving clarification to the top of this post: When the mouse is not hovering over a certain div, I want elements other than this div to have a red background-color. Can this be achieved with a not() selector as seen in this post? **The predicament appears to be that since the certain div is within a body element, the mouse will always be hovering over the body element even when it's over the certain div, thus the body will always have a red background-color.**

I am trying to use the not() selector to affect elements when hovering over elements that are not within my selection.

For example:

```css
    [data-panel] { background-color:white; }

    :not([data-panel=visible]):hover { background-color:red; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div data-panel='visible'>
    <div data-panel='visible'>Content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My desired outcome is that if the mouse is hovering anywhere besides those `div`s, the background-color will change to red (i.e. hovering in the body).

However, since those `div`s are within the body, that selector will always be active. The body will always be red. Is there anyway to style those `div`s so that this doesn't happen? Maybe something with `z-index`? Any clues?

Comment: FYI, you should use `data-panel`, not `panel`, as `panel` is not a valid HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with CSS alone.

To achieve that effect – let the body turn red on :hover, but not when hovering the panels – you have to cancel the pointer event bubbling on the panels. This is only possible using JS.

BTW, HTML5 has a method to define own attributes: [the `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes); e.g. `data-panel="visible"`.

Comment: As you can see in your code snippet, the body still becomes red when hovering over the div with Content. This is the root of my question.

Comment: @ferr Mmh, I understood as as the target behavior; You can exclude the body tag by just targeting all elements within it (see updated answer). But you should clarify your question and define what your target behavior is…

Comment: That's in my "desired outcome". I'll test your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't appear to work. To clarify: The background should be red iff the mouse is hovering anywhere except over the specified divs.

Comment: You can't do that in CSS, as you have to disable the pass-through of pointer events on the panels.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as an answer. It's unfortunate, I hoped for some magical CSS to make this work. Could you clarify your post to suggest that it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote your attribute selector.

As [already mentioned by James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428315/css3-not-selector-working-around-contained-elements/26428349#comment41501646_26428315); `panel` is not a valid HTML5 attribute. You should be taking advantage of HTML5's `data-*` attributes.

```css
:not([data-panel=visible]):hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div data-panel='visible'>
  <div data-panel='visible'>Content</div>
</div>
```

This of course, affects all elements that don't have the matching attribute, including **`<body>`**, which is while your entire page's background will turn red when hovered.

**Edit**

> The predicament appears to be that since the certain div is within a body element, the mouse will always be hovering over the body element even when it's over the certain div, thus the body will always have a red background-color

There is no CSS parent selector, so an event on an element within the body, can't have any say over any styles applied to the body.

Comment: mistake on using quotes, was typing directly.

Comment: I am not seeing an answer to my question here. Is this not possible with css3 alone?